# Wordpress websites doesn't load assets behind a company firewall

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, firewall

I encounter I problem where our wordpress websites assets doesn't load getting 403 Forbidden in a company network which uses a firewall.

The thing is that those same websites in production, which are managed by another company (but still in amazon aws servers) load fine, but the same website in our server fails. So that's why I think it could be something related with the server configuration.

And this doesn't happen with other kind of websites like an Angular APP that we have.

And the server IP or domain isn't blacklisted.

What could be happen?

Comment: Follow this article https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: mmm but my apache user owns the folder and files and the webs load fine from any other network, why would be a permission issue? doesn't have to happend in all scenarios if that would be the case?